# Stop-ServiceFabricNode cmdlet causes Azure Service Fabric Cluster connection to not respond

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric, powershell-cmdlet

I wanted to stop the nodes of one of the service fabric cluster resource(with 5 nodes) I have, so I used `Stop-ServiceFabricNode`. I did it for 3 nodes successfully, the 4th one caused my PowerShell ISE to hang and I had to cancel it midway. After which I am not able to connect to my service fabric instance.

When I try and use the `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` I get error saying:

```
WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
WARNING: Failed to contact Failover Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM...
False
WARNING: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed becau
se connected host has failed to respond <IP>
Connect-serviceFabricCluster : No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS issue.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-serviceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint "<resourcename>.w ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], FabricException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster
```

Please do let me know how do I enable the connection back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST api that you're talking to through PowerShell runs on the nodes you've shut down. At some point they are no longer available:

> The Stop-ServiceFabricNode cmdlet stops the node that you specify with
>   the NodeName parameter by stopping the Fabric.exe process, which stops
>   all of the system service and user service replicas hosted on that
>   Service Fabric node.

One of the following options may work. Hopefully option 1:

1. RDP in all stopped nodes and execute `Start-SeviceFabricNode` [script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt644771.aspx) with IpAddressOrFQDN and ClusterConnectionPort pointing to the node ip address and port.

> The Start-ServiceFabricNode cmdlet starts the node specified by the
>   NodeName parameter that has been stopped using the
>   Stop-ServiceFabricNode cmdlet

### Danger zone:

2. From the Azure Portal, restart your VM scale set. **may cause data loss**
3. From the Azure Portal, reallocate your VM scale set. **will cause data loss**
4. Recreate your cluster **will cause data loss**